# Jquery error message showing on every fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a html form and in some of the fields only digits to be submitted. If text is entered, it will show error message. It is working not up to the marks. Out of three fiels, if some body enters any text, its showing error message in all the three filed.

What I want is- the error message to be shown for the current field instead of all the filed.

**The Jquery code is:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $(".quantity").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $(".errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

**The HTML CODE is:**

```
<form method="post" name="data" action="  ">
     Amount:  <span class="errmsg"></span><br>
     <input type="text" name="amount" class="quantity" /><br><br>
     Interest:  <span class="errmsg"></span><br>
     <input type="text" name="interest" class="quantity" /><br><br>
     Duration: <span class="errmsg"></span><br>
     <input type="text" name="duration" class="quantity" /><br><br>
     <input type="submit" name='submit'  onclick="show_confirm()" value="SUBMIT"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.prev()` to select the error message span before the input

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $(".quantity").keypress(function (e) {
    var elem =$(this);
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        elem.prev().prev(".errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
The HTML CODE is:

<form method="post" name="data" action="  ">
     Amount:  <span class="errmsg"></span><br>
     <input type="text" name="amount" class="quantity" /><br><br>
     Interest:  <span class="errmsg"></span><br>
     <input type="text" name="interest" class="quantity" /><br><br>
     Duration: <span class="errmsg"></span><br>
     <input type="text" name="duration" class="quantity" /><br><br>
     <input type="submit" name='submit'  onclick="show_confirm()" value="SUBMIT"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $(".quantity").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message        
        $(this).prevAll(".errmsg").first().html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".quantity").keypress(function (e) {
   var name = $(this).prop('name');

     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        $(".errmsg#err-"+name).html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
  return false;
    }
   });
});

function show_confirm(){}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" name="data" action="  ">
     Amount:  <span class="errmsg" id="err-amount"></span><br>
     <input type="text" name="amount" class="quantity" /><br><br>
     
     Interest:  <span class="errmsg" id="err-interest"></span><br>
     <input type="text" name="interest" class="quantity" /><br><br>
     
     Duration: <span class="errmsg" id="err-duration"></span><br>
     <input type="text" name="duration" class="quantity" /><br><br>
     
     <input type="submit" name='submit'  onclick="show_confirm()" value="SUBMIT"> 
</form>
```

I created an `id` for each of the error messages (I made them the same as the `name` attribute of the input). Then I got that name, and used it to dynamically look up the id of the error message.